# JavaScript: Why isn't my closure working?

Tags: javascript, closures

The following code is only assigning the value of the last `.enter_form input` to the last `MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form[key]` (where `key` is the only thing that varies). I think it's because only the last value of the key is being passed to `addEntry()`, but I can't figure out how to get around that.

```
$('.enter_form input').each(function() {
    var key = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    userDict[key] = val;
    MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form = [];
    function addEntry() {
        return function(k) {
            MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form[k] =  {'entry': userDict[k]};
        }(key);
    }
    addEntry();
}
```

Comment: What is the code *supposed* to do? I've guessed at it in my answer, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addEntry function is redundant since each iteration is already run inside it´s own scope so `key` and `val` are preserved properly (hope that explanation makes sense). Also the array you where inserting into was overwritten each iteration as well, so at the end of the `.each()` you end up with an array with only 1 value. It should also be an object rather then an array, even if the id's are numerical.

```
// you where overwriting this each iteration
MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form = {};

$('.enter_form input').each(function() {

    var el= $(this); // cache instead of creating a new jQuery object each time
    var key = el.attr('id');
    var val = el.val();

    userDict[key] = val;
    MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form[key] =  {'entry': userDict[key]};

}); // ); was also missing
```

Should work.

Comment: *"Your addEntry returns a function which in turn is never executed."* No it doesn't. It returns the return value of the function it creates (note the `(key)` at the very end). Or at least, it's clearly meant to; as it is, I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error (for reasons related to the grammar, to *actually* execute a function you've just created in an expression, you have to surround the function expression with parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to work out what it's meant to do, but I think this is probably it:

```
MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form = [];
$('.enter_form input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        key = this.id,
        val = $this.val();
    userDict[key] = val;
    MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form[key] = {
        'entry': val
    };
});
```

That's based on your saying that *"...`key` is the only thing that varies"* (presumably `$(this).val()` also varies, but I took your point). It will add entries to `MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form` for each of the form's `input` `id`s, as well as adding them to the `userDict` map.

As a side note, if the `id` values on the `input` elements aren't purely numeric, then I suspect you want to start with a blank *object*:

```
MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form = {};
//                                                ^^-- change is here
```

...rather than an empty array:

```
MYAPP.list[0].responses[MYAPP.score.round].form = [];
```

...although since arrays are objects, it works even if you're adding non-numeric properties.

---

**Off-topic**: No need for `$(this).attr('id')`. Just use `this.id`.